# How to hide the Download dialog in WebView2 while downloading page content or printing with "Save as PDF" option?

Tags: winforms, webview2

I know how to subscribe to the `CoreWebview2.DownloadStarting` event and use `handled = true` to stop the Download dialog from showing while a download (i.e. an image) is being made, but the problem is the `DownloadStarting` event *never fires* if you right click on a web page and choose "Save as" or "Print > Save as PDF", even though the Download dialog *will* appear as if a regular download was being made. Does anyone know any workaround for this?

My code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (webView != null)
        webView.Dispose();

    webView = new WebView2();
    await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
    webView.CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting += CoreWebView2_DownloadStarting;
    panel1.Controls.Add(webView);
    webView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    webView.Source = new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com");
}

private void CoreWebView2_DownloadStarting(object sender, CoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs e)
{
      e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just found a solution:

1. subscribe to `CoreWebView2.IsDefaultDownloadDialogOpenChanged` event:

```
webView.CoreWebView2.IsDefaultDownloadDialogOpenChanged += webView_CoreWebView2_IsDefaultDownloadDialogOpenChanged;
```

2. Close the Download dialog if it's open:

```
private void webView_CoreWebView2_IsDefaultDownloadDialogOpenChanged(object sender, object e)
{
   if (webView.CoreWebView2.IsDefaultDownloadDialogOpen) webView.CoreWebView2.CloseDefaultDownloadDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the previous posters said, there is the `IsDefaultDownloadDialogOpenChanged` event, of the `CoreWebView2` class. But instead of explictly closing the dialog "manually", by using the `CloseDefaultDownloadDialog()` method, you can set `e.Handled = true` in the event handler, to prevent WebView2 from displaying the dialog.

But the even better approach is to not do this in the `IsDefaultDownloadDialogOpenChanged` event, but instead in the `DownloadStarting` event, of the `CoreWebView2` class. It works exactly the same and `e.Handled = true` in the event handler prevents WebView2 from displaying the dialog at all.

Microsoft also mentions this here, in a comment in the *Examples* section in url#1 and in the *Remarks* section in url#2:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.downloadstarting
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.isdefaultdownloaddialogopenchanged

**TLDR;** --> **Attach to `DownloadStarting` event and set `e.Handled = true` in the event handler.**

Have fun.